# How to verify which flags were read using Getopt::Long in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, getopt-long

> **myscript.pl**

```
my $R;
my $f1 = "f1.log";
my $f2 = "f2.log";
my $f3 = "f3.log";

sub checkflags {

    GetOptions('a=s'    => \$f1,
               'b=s'    => \$f2,
               'c=s'    => \$f3,
    );

    open $R, '>', $f1 or die "Cannot open file\n"; # Line a
}
```

- All the flags are optional.
- If I call the script as

  ```
  perl myscript.pl -a=filename
  ```

  I need to append a `.log` to the filename before opening it at `Line a`.
- For that I need to know whether `GetOptions` read something into `$f1` or not.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to look for `/[.]log$/` in `$f1` and add it if it isn't present.  Unfortunately that means that when the user passes in `"foo.log"` and wanted it to become `"foo.log.log"` it won't, but I think we can agree that user is a jerk.

A better option, that will make the jerk happy, is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    'a=s'    => \my $f1,
    'b=s'    => \my $f2,
    'c=s'    => \my $f3,
);

if (defined $f1) {
    $f1 .= ".log";
} else {
    $f1 = "f1.log";
}

print "$f1\n";
```

If you want to define all of default names at the top, use a different variable to do that (it is probably better reading code anyway):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my $default_f1 = "f1.log";
my $default_f2 = "f2.log";
my $default_f3 = "f3.log";

GetOptions(
    'a=s'    => \my $f1,
    'b=s'    => \my $f2,
    'c=s'    => \my $f3,
);

if (defined $f1) {
    $f1 .= ".log";
} else {
    $f1 = $default_f1;
}

print "$f1\n";
```

Comment: They could always just pass `foo.log.log` if they *really* wanted that filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (defined $f1) {
  # You got a -a option
}
```

But personally I'd prefer to [read the options into a hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Storing-options-values-in-a-hash) and then use exists().

Comment: that will always be true because of the initialization that I have at Line 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
$f1 = "$f1.log" unless $f1 =~ m/\.log$/i;
```

Appends the *log* extension if the file name does not already have one. Since the default value ends in *log*, nothing happens. And it works if the user types the *log* on the command line.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how the append using `m/\.log$/i` happens?

Comment: What about the user who wants the log to be named `foo.log.log`?

Comment: The append happens in the assignment: $f1 = "$f1.log".

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) and [MooseX::Getopt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Getopt):

```
package MyApp;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
with 'MooseX::Getopt';

has f1 => (
    is => 'ro', isa => 'Str',
    cmd_aliases => 'a',
    default => 'f1.log',
    predicate => 'has_a',
);
has f2 => (
    is => 'ro', isa => 'Str',
    cmd_aliases => 'b',
    default => 'f2.log',
    predicate => 'has_b',
);
has f3 => (
    is => 'ro', isa => 'Str',
    cmd_aliases => 'c',
    default => 'f3.log',
    predicate => 'has_c',
);

# this is run immediately after construction
sub BUILD
{
    my $this = shift;

    print "a was provided\n" if $this->has_a;
    print "b was provided\n" if $this->has_b;
    print "c was provided\n" if $this->has_c;
}

1;
```